# Wiki for developers

Tags: wiki

I need a wiki software for developers.

This means:

- Content is written in a markup language like markdown or asciidoc.
- Good syntax highlighting for major programming languages.
- Tracking of changes.
- Good search functionality.
- It should be possible to automatically generate or update pages (by e.g. REST).

I would prefer a system with easy export of the content.

It may be free or not. It is more important that it is well maintained and will probably not be abandoned soon.

I would like to run it on our own linux server.

Comment: Did you check with [Gitea](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/)? You can easily self-host it (even on a Raspi), and besides a Wiki using Markdown it's also an issue tracker and Git server – like a lightweight Github or GitLab. I didn't check the syntax highlighting for many languages – but they have a test setup you could try it on. Or go straight for Codeberg.org to check existing wikis (Codeberg is a non-profit mainly targeting FOSS).